# Not able to access Nginx from an external IP even after k8s nodeport service exposed

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I am not able to access the nginx server using http://:30602 and also http://:30602

**OS: Ubuntu 22**

I also checked if any firewall is blocking it.

**Using ufw**

```
admin@tst-server:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

**Using netstat**

```
admin@tst-server:~$ netstat -an | grep 22 | grep -i listen
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     354787   /run/containerd/s/9a866c6ea3a4fe1976aaed0884400cd59228d43776774cc3fad2d0b9a7c2ed7b
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21722    /run/systemd/private
admin@tst-server:~$ netstat -an | grep 30602 | grep -i listen
```

Commands used for nginx deployment

**Create Deployment**

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx
kubectl get deployments
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
myapp   2/2     2            2           8d
nginx   1/1     1            1           9m50s
```

**Create Service**

```
kubectl create service nodeport nginx --tcp=80:80
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        8d
nginx        NodePort    10.109.112.116   <none>        80:30602/TCP   10m
```

**Test it out**

```
admin@tst-server:~$ hostname
tst-server.com

admin@tst-server:~$ curl tst-server.com:30602
curl: (7) Failed to connect to tst-server.com port 30602 after 10 ms: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by getting the Node IP address for Minikube using following command

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

and then

```
curl  http://<node_ip>:30008
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon curl test-server.com:30602 why it redirects to tst-server.kanaaritech.com?
To check whether the node port is working or not you can check once with the node's IP with port 30602.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is the same server and is not getting redirected. Some typo while doing Find & Replace. Fixed the original question.

Comment: okay, It seems you have followed the standard process and that should work fine if the cluster is healthy. To me please try to curl the pod IP and see if you are getting a response or not from inside the cluster. Next, if pod IP is reachable may be an issue with kube-proxy. Bounce the kube-proxy and check.